# Entity Framework without DB

Tags: c#

Is it possible to work with Entity Framework without a database, using the generation of data and relations from code, by initializing and populating the model? For this you need to write a custom DbContext and DbSet?

Comment: Yes, you can use In-Memory data provider.

Comment: @Fabio interesting, I wasn't aware of that. But, being in-memory, presumably it doesn't persist for long?

Comment: @ADyson, as long as your application running.

Comment: @Fabio I can not find "In-Memory" in EF Full. Is it an analogue of this in a full version EF, not a core?

Comment: No, In-Memory is available only for EF Core. Another option to use Sqlite provider with ":memory:" option.

Comment: @Fabio And if you do not use DbContext, but only DbSet <T>?

Comment: What features of Entity Framework you actually need?

Comment: @Fabio the server returns packets as models from the database, but in my API I would like to abstract those same server models (to make wrapper classes). And with the possibility of relational access to other objects through the properties of the parent object. How convenient is it possible to implement with the help, but only without the participation of the database (since the packages are deserialized straight from the server)?